# Предварительная загрузка

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть много картинок, и чтобы сделать предварительную загрузку не комильфо прогонять каждый путь через массив, ибо путей много и вручную делать долго. Как можно сделать по другому? Мой вариант будет правильным? При нажатии на маленькое изображение должно появляться большое без загрузки.

```js
$('.wrapper img').each(function(){
var att =$(this).attr('src');
var qwe = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
att=att.replace(qwe,'_q.jpg');
var newI= $('<img src="'+att+'">');
$(this).click(function(){ 
$('.open').append('newI');
});
});
```

Comment: Есть мнение,что при большом количестве картинок не комильфо делать предварительную загрузку, но делать отложенную загрузку как раз самое комильфо.

Comment: имелось в виду предварительную загрузку именно через массив

Comment: вы хотите набить массив имён?

Comment: Я хочу сделать предзагрузку не используя массив, потому что картинок слишком много и вбивать каждый путь долго.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $('.open').append('newI');

`newI` должен быть именем переменной, а не строкой

```js
$('.wrapper img').each(function(){
  var att =$(this).attr('src');
  var qwe = /\d+/;
  att=att.replace(qwe, 250);
  var newI= $('<img src="'+att+'">');

  $(this).click(function(){ 
    $('.open').append(newI);
  });
});
```

```css
.open, .wrapper{display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
 <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200">
</div>

<div class="open"></div>
```

Comment: Значит это будет корректной предзагрузкой всех изображений?

Comment: Да, вы можете убедиться в F12-Network - картинка загружается до добавления в DOM

Comment: Всё спасибо. Ото по логике вроде загружается, а проверить не мог.

Answer (score 0):

для открытия модального окна используйте библиотеку [FancyBox3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Пример работы библиотеки FancyBox 3</title>
<!-- Просьба! Дабы не нагружать slyfox.kz, при копировании примера
скачать оригинальный дистрибутив библиотеки http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/ -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//slyfox.kz/vendor/fancyBox-3.0/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">

<style>
  p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p><strong>Щелкни на картинку:</strong></p>
<div>

  <!-- для href ставим путь на большую картинку -->
  <a href="https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/c/bf/romby-uzory-cvety.jpg" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Красивая текстура">
    <!-- для src ставим путь на уменьшенную копию -->
    <img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/middle/c/bf/romby-uzory-cvety.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="https://img1.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/4/d4/soedinennye-shtaty-vashington-3647.jpg" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Ночной город">
    <img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/middle/4/d4/soedinennye-shtaty-vashington-3647.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="https://img2.goodfon.ru/original/1920x1080/2/9e/ch-b-komediya-aleksey-chadov.jpg" data-fancybox="group" data-caption="Алексей Чадов">
    <img src="https://img2.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/middle/2/9e/ch-b-komediya-aleksey-chadov.jpg">
  </a>

</div>
</body>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//slyfox.kz/vendor/fancyBox-3.0/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Демонстрацию работы можно посмотреть тут https://codepen.io/lukas-pierce/pen/ZLNBmR

Comment: Да нет. Я хочу сам написать скрипт для предварительной загрузки